# Question regarding SQL arithmetic functions

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

Can you tell me what am I doing wrong here? Trying to use subtraction here in SQL Server 2005 `SELECT` statement. There's some type of syntax error here.

```
isnull(dbo.udf_GetInventory(ga.sku,@date4),0) * costprice - 
isnull(dbo.udf_GetInventory(ga.sku,@date3),0) * costprice  as  date2_diff
```

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: Did you mean to have two different @date variables?

Comment: Why don't you replace all of that with 0? That's what the result is going to be.

Comment: Even though the order of operations is probably correct, for maintenance reasons it is best to use parentheses so furture maintainers know what order you intended. select (isnull(dbo.udf_GetInventory(ga.sku,@date4),0) * costprice) - (isnull(dbo.udf_GetInventory(ga.sku,@date3),0) * costprice) is what I expect you are going for but don't know for sure.

Answer (score 4):

There is no syntax-error here if:

1. You put the statement in a SELECT ... from ga.
2. ga is a table that has columns sku and costprice of some numeric data type.
3. You have a scalar-valued function called udf_getinventory that takes two parameters.
4. The data type of the first parameter to udf_getinventory matches the data type of ga.sku.
5. The data type of the second parameter matches the data type of @date3.
6. udf_getinventory returns some numeric data type.
7. @Date3 is declared before the SELECT statement.
8. @Date4 is declared before the SELECT statement.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about a syntax error, but assuming udf_GetInventory is non-deterministic you're going to get 0 every time...